# algorithm for custom DatePicker

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, uipickerview

I'm working on a custom `UIPickerView` that will show times. I need them to match what the website shows below.

The time will start at `x` but for now that is midnight (it can be anytime). It will then increment intervals of `i`. For the below image `i = 7`.

The problem I am running into is when I change the hour, for example **1am**, the minutes will need to change as well so that the user can only pick a minute for that hour, that is in increments of `i`, but I'm not sure the correct algorithm to run.

For now I am using `60 % i == 0` then use the `UIDatePicker` and setting `minuteInterval` to `i`, but if `60 % i != 0` that is where I need to use this customer picker.

Can anyone help me with an algorithm that would provide me the number of rows for the *hours*, *minutes* and as well populate the hours and minutes based on the interval?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you anything about objective-c, or ios, or uipickerview... For the algorithm.  Here is some pseudo code in no language in particular:

```
i = 7      // this is i in your example
offset=420 // This is where you could say you want 
           // to start at 7:00 (420 minutes after midnight) 
           // you could use any number here obviously.
counter = offset
while (counter<1440+offset){
    counter = counter+i
    minutes = counter%60
    hours   = counter/60  // Use integer division 
}
```

The modulous gives you your minutes every time by giving you the remainder..  So in your example minutes would go from 56 => 63 => 3 which is what you want.

if you just want to know what the minutes and hours will be for a given interval (suppose the intervals go from 0 to 206 (there are 206 7 minute intervals in a day) then you would do the following:

```
minutes = (i*intervalNum) % 60
hours =   (i*intervalNum) / 60    // Integer division!
```

If you need the number of intervals in a time period you could do the following:

```
keep a hashmap (again I don't know how objective-c handles these) that maps an hour to a list of the minutes that mark intervals.  In your example you could have a hashmap that looks like:

{0 => (0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56),
 1 => (3,10,17,24,31,38,45,52,59),
 2 => (6,13,20,27,34,41,48,55),
 ...
}
```

You would build this map during the first round through.  To get the number of intervals in the 2-3 timeslot just return map[2].length (or whatever its equivalent).

Obviously this is one of MANY ways to do this and one would need much more context to go into any further detail.

Good Luck

Comment: this definitly gets me pointed in the right direction. One thing though is how would I get the number of minute intervals for a given period? In my screenshot they both have 8 - 7 minute intervals, except the last one has 7 - 7 minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ajon I came up with this code

```
NSInteger counter = startTime;
while (counter + minuteInterval < endTime) {
    counter = counter + minuteInterval;
    NSLog(@"Hours: %d Minutes: %d", counter / 60, counter % 60);
}
```

I had to do a little bit of modification but am posting my code incase anyone else runs into this issue. I am marking his as the answer since it provided the base for this code.